# Libvirtd Fails to Start

Tags: kvm, gentoo, libvirt

I am using wifi, but libvirtd is trying to use eth0:

```
gentoo /var/log # service libvirtd start
 * Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]
 * Bringing up interface eth0
 *   config_eth0 not specified; defaulting to DHCP
 *   dhcp ...
 *     Running dhcpcd ...
eth0: waiting for carrier
timed out
dhcpcd exited [ !! ]
 * ERROR: net.eth0 failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start libvirtd as net.eth0 would not start
```

How can I get it to start without a wired connection?

Comment: You need to remove the dependency in libvirtd's init script. Are you using OpenRC or Systemd?

Comment: I'm using OpenRC. But I gave up on using wireless and just hooked the system up to a wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

The libvirtd OpenRC init script depends on `net` by default. if `rc_depend_strict` is set to `YES` (the default) in `/etc/rc.conf`, every service in `/etc/init.d/net.*` needs to be started to satisfy the dependency.

There are 2 options: Either change `rc_need="net"` to `rc_need="net.wlan0"` (change wlan0 to your wlan device name) in `/etc/conf.d/libvirtd` or set `rc_depend_strict="NO"` in `/etc/rc.conf`.